# Solr won't add my fields : schema.xml

Tags: xml, indexing, solr

I am working with Solr 5.2.1 , i got everything working fine but i can't add field to index. 
Here is my schema.xml

```
      <schema name="example" version="1.5"> 
<fields>
    <field name="COTID" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
     <field name="COTREF" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <field name="COTTYPEREF" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <field name="COTTYPE" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false"/>
     <field name="COTTEXTE" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="true"/>
</fields>
<uniqueKey>COTID</uniqueKey>
<types>
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true"/>
<fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
<fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
<!-- lots of details -->
</fieldType>
<fieldType name="currency" class="solr.CurrencyField" precisionStep="8" defaultCurrency="USD" currencyConfig="currency.xml"/>
</types>
</schema>
```

can you help please ? 
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you added a new field to your schema.xml and, when you did a full-import, the new field didn't show up? If that's the case, did you restart Solr? Did you update your data-config.xml (or whatever you're using) to pull the new field in?

Comment: i did restart it, yes i edited the data-config.xml with a sql query and fileds

Comment: hello, did you reach a solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you modify any of Solr configuration files you need to Restart your Solr so that it starts according to your configuration setting. you should restart Solr or reload your core and check what error you are getting.

(refer below URL, change URL names according to you) to reload core

> http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD&core=core1

Comment: i did, but i still dont my fields in the "Schema browser" section an no Processed results : Requests: 1 (1/s), Fetched: 10796 (10796/s), Skipped: 0, Processed: 0 (0/s)